# Why am I required to re-authenticate with SF more often last few weeks?

Tags: support

Over the last few weeks, my session with SE sites expire a lot more frequently than it used to before.

It seems arbitrary. Sometimes it's after hours of inactivity, other times (like just now) I'm logged in and, after clicking through a link, I noticed I am logged out.

I authenticate using OAuth via Google if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've noticed this as well. I have no hard evidence to support this claim, but perhaps it has something to do with with SE's increasing usage of Cloudflare.

Comment: Me too, and on other sites as well, which makes me want to migrate this to [meta.se] if you agree.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because lately they've done several failovers and failbacks between their primary and secondary DCs, and when they do this, the authentication tokens don't come over.

Comment: @Sven, please do. Wasn't sure if it was an SE-wide issue. Also, this just happened now---was logged in, saw 2 comments in my inbox but when I clicked on them nothing was happening. Refreshed and saw that I was logged out again.

Comment: I'll also add that it depends on what authentication method you're using. This hasn't had any noticeable impact on Google authentication.

Comment: I auth through Google. Has certainly been noticeable to me but that's anecdotal I suppose.

Comment: Bad assumption on my part then. I haven't been hit with any re-auth requests in the past week even after being hit by maintenance splash pages.

Comment: So I use Google auth as well, and I've been presented the non-logged-in front page twice tonight. Each time though, I click the "log in" link and then I get signed in automatically.

Comment: @EEAA my same experience. It's certainly happening more often lately.

Comment: Is it just SF where you get logged out or on other sites as well?

Comment: I initially noticed it on SF but just realized it on SO. To be fair though, I am not on SO as much.